# How best to optimise this small bit of c# Linq code

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, optimization

If you take a look at our arcade homepage:

http://www.scirra.com/arcade

In the top right there is a box showing the last people who played this game.  In the profiler I'm using, it shows this as taking 900ms to run which is about 80% of the total page load time.

The query is relatively simple:

```
// Recent players
using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
{
    var q = (from c in db.tblArcadeGamePlays
                join a in db.tblProfiles on c.UserID equals a.UserID
                where c.UserID != 0
                select new
                {
                    c.UserID,
                    c.tblForumAuthor.Username,
                    a.EmailAddress,
                    Date = (from d in db.tblArcadeGamePlays where d.UserID == c.UserID orderby d.Date descending select new { d.Date }).Take(1).Single().Date
                })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
    .Take(16);
```

But it's too slow for my needs.

An output cache on this would not be suitable because it would be nice for this box to be in real time.  Also, 900ms ontop of normal page load is too slow even for one user every now and then so would like to avoid that if possible.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can speed this up?  My two ideas at the moment are to have:

- A new database table that holds the last players removing the need for the join
- A field stored somewhere that holds the HTML of that box, every new play that happens it rebuilds that field
- Combination of the both

Both sort of ugly!  Any help appreciated.

**As requested, linqpad results**

**Lambda**

```
TblArcadeGamePlays
   .Join (
      TblProfiles, 
      c => c.UserID, 
      a => a.UserID, 
      (c, a) => 
         new  
         {
            c = c, 
            a = a
         }
   )
   .Where (temp0 => (temp0.c.UserID != 0))
   .Select (
      temp0 => 
         new  
         {
            UserID = temp0.c.UserID, 
            Username = temp0.c.User.Username, 
            EmailAddress = temp0.a.EmailAddress, 
            Date = TblArcadeGamePlays
               .Where (d => (d.UserID == temp0.c.UserID))
               .OrderByDescending (d => d.Date)
               .Select (
                  d => 
                     new  
                     {
                        Date = d.Date
                     }
               )
               .Take (1)
               .Single ().Date
         }
   )
   .Distinct ()
   .OrderByDescending (c => c.Date)
   .Take (16)
```

**SQL**

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (16) [t6].[UserID], [t6].[Username], [t6].[EmailAddress], [t6].[value] AS [Date2]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [t5].[UserID], [t5].[Username], [t5].[EmailAddress], [t5].[value]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[UserID], [t2].[Username], [t1].[EmailAddress], (
            SELECT [t4].[Date]
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[Date]
                FROM [tblArcadeGamePlays] AS [t3]
                WHERE [t3].[UserID] = [t0].[UserID]
                ORDER BY [t3].[Date] DESC
                ) AS [t4]
            ) AS [value]
        FROM [tblArcadeGamePlays] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [tblProfile] AS [t1] ON [t0].[UserID] = [t1].[UserID]
        INNER JOIN [tblForumAuthor] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Author_ID] = [t0].[UserID]
        ) AS [t5]
    WHERE [t5].[UserID] <> @p0
    ) AS [t6]
ORDER BY [t6].[value] DESC
```

**Query Plan**

[image]

Comment: Try using a group by rather than a distinct.

Comment: I'm assuming this is LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: You can also use SQL Profiler to find out exactly what query is being generated and how long does it take. If you've never used SQL Profiler here is a very good [tutorial by Brent Ozar](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler)

Comment: @Carlos thanks, I don't have a profiler with this edition though, I might buy the dev edition for developing though as I think that includes it and might be useful now for me

Comment: That seems like a ridiculously complex query for the information you're trying to get out of the database.  Might be worth trying to write it in SQL and work backwards from that to LINQ?

Answer (score 5):

I'd be willing to bet pretty good money that virtually all of the delay you are seeing comes from the database itself, not the LINQ (making this a database optimization question, not a LINQ optimization question).

I'd use linqpad to have a peek at what query is being generated (see: http://www.thereforesystems.com/view-t-sql-query-generated-by-linq-to-sql-using-linqpad/), and post that here.  A query plan from running that query in SQL Management Studio (assuming that you are using SQL Server) would also be helpful.

OK, given the edits, try something like this.  It should simplify the query dramatically:

```
using (MainContext db = new MainContext())
{
    var latestIds = db.tblArcadeGamePlays.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).Select(c => c.UserID).Distinct().Take(16); // These are the 16 most recent player Ids.
    // join them here to the rest of those player's data
    var playerData = ... // you'll need to fill in here some by filtering the other data you want using latestIds.Contains
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris, great tool thanks for the link!  I've posted the linqpad results in the question.  I'll look up the query plan now

Comment: Wow, my eyes are burning. I almost wish I hadn't asked!

Comment: Just added the query plan, I'm new to these features so I hope I've posted the right thing. 30% of it seems to be a index seek on tblForumAuthor, another 25% on sorting something, not sure what exactly

Comment: lol don't worry if it's too much to sift through but any help you can give is much appreciated!

Comment: @TomGullen did you try my simplified Date query to see if that makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the issue, but your date query could be simplified to this:

```
Date = (from d in db.tblArcadeGamePlays 
        where d.UserID == c.UserID 
        orderby d.Date descending 
        select d.Date).First()
```

Maybe the round-about query was confusing the optimizer.  Otherwise I agree with the other answers, check the generated SQL query and check your indices.

Also, are you sure `Distinct` is necessary and that it does what you think?  It will only filter out duplicates that have the same value for every field/column.

Comment: Thanks, this shaved ~15% of the total execution time!

Comment: @TomGullen cool.  Try removing the `Distinct` and a) seeing if the results are different (most important) and b) seeing if it's faster.  I'm thinking it'll be faster, and I'm fairly sure the results will be the same but not 100% sure

Comment: can't remove the distinct otherwise we get the same player.  For example, if I play 3 games in a row, without the distinct my name would come up 3 times when I only want it coming up once.

Comment: @TomGullen Hmm, so I'm guessing `tblProfiles` to `tblArcadeGamePlays` is a one-to-many, but it also seems like the only reason you need to join to `tblArcadeGamePlays` is to get to `tblForumAuthor`.  Does `tblForumAuthor` have a foreign key to `tblProfiles` and are they one-to-one?  If so you could skip the `tblArcadeGamePlays` in the join and that way you wouldn't need the `Distinct`.  I think the `Distinct` call is partially responsible for the slowness, so if you could avoid it that might help.

Comment: yes you're right, `tblProfiles` and `tblAuthor` are one-to-one relationship, it was a design choice (bad one at that) I made early on to keep the forum software separate to my website.  The `UserID` in `tblArcadeGamePlays` can refer either to `tblProfile.UserID` or `tblForumAuthor.Author_ID` but no relationship is set up with tblForumAuthor yet

Comment: I think I'm going to create a globally accessible stack object where each new play pushes their data onto the stack.  The stack can then simply be read for display purposes.  I think this should be a lot faster

Comment: @TomGullen Also, another option would be to store a dictionary of UserID/Author_ID in memory that way you don't need to do the awkward join every time.  It won't be as nice as a single LINQ query but it would probably be faster.

Comment: Or if the author name can't change, or doesn't need to be always up to date, you could just make the dictionary store the author name and skip the lookup.

Comment: Bah just remembered we use a static server to log game plays, a global stack wouldn't really be possible as it wouldn't know when to update.  I could do a cache stored in a table in the DB but that's ugly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes on both sides of the join.

Answer (score 0):

Run the SQL Server Database Tuning Wizard ( in SQL Management Studio / Tools) against your database  with these queries and let it create statistics and indexes to tune your database for performance.
How many people would recommend this? It works.