# ASP.NET C# globally available object

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack, global-asax

How would I add a `Stack` object into my `global.asax` so it's accessible by the entire application?  At the moment I have:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Global vars
    Application.Add("ArcadeTotalUniquePlayers", 0);
    Application.Add("ArcadeTotalPlays", 0);
    Stack<int> ArcadeLastPlayers = new Stack<int>(16);
```

The first two variables work, but I'm not sure how to make the `Stack` globally accessible.

Comment: Where do you actually need to use this object?  This seems like a design issue.

Comment: @Ek0nomik it's related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797520/how-best-to-optimise-this-small-bit-of-c-sharp-linq-code I'm experimenting with using a global stack to optimise a slow piece of code

Comment: @Ek0nomik - I agree, a mutable stack available globally sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
Application.Add("ArcadeLastPlayers", new Stack<int>());
```

and then

```
((Stack<int>)Application["ArcadeLastPlayers"]).Pop();
```

Or you could make some sort of global static, so you don't have to cast it every time you need to retrieve it:

```
namespace GlobalUtils {
    public static class ArcadeData {
        public static Stack<int> ArcadeLastPlayers = new Stack<int>();
    }
}
```

and then

```
GlobalUtils.ArcadeData.ArcadeLastPlayers.Pop();
```

Comment: thanks, I'm new to global.asax, would I declare that class in global.asax, and how would I access the values from a content page?

Comment: No, just declare the class anywhere in the world, make sure you website has access to it, then in any of your pages or controls you'd just say  `Namespace.Utils.ArcadeLastPlayers.Pop();`

Comment: Utils.ArcadeLastPlayers based on the example here.

Comment: @TomGullen, no, the class can be declared anywhere (though preferably in its own file, properly namespaced ;)).  you would then just call the public member from the static class whenever you needed to get/set the values in the stack

Answer (score 2):

If you want use the HttpApplcationState, you should be able to just do the following:

```
Application.Add("ArcadeLastPlayers", new Stack<int>(16));
```

[HttpApplicationState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.add.aspx) takes a string for the  name and an object as the associated value. All you would have to do is cast it to a Stack when you retrieve the "ArcadeLastPlayers" value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) - place the `.cs` file in your `app_code` folder and bob's your auntie.